# Linear Transformation $T$ is bounded in the unit ball then $T$ is bounded in any ball

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $T : (X, \|\cdot\|_{X}) \rightarrow (Y, \|\cdot\|_{Y})$ a linear transformation.Show that the following statements are equivalent.

1. T is continuous in all X
2. T is bounded in the unit ball (open or closed)
3. T is bounded on any ball in space.

I have some trobules to prove 2. implies 3. I tried to do it from induction in the ball's radius, thus if i consider this radius as $\epsilon=n>0$ for $n=1$ i have 2. but for $n+1$ i don't have any idea.

Comment: If you introduce a multiplicative factor $\lambda$, how does the image of $\lambda\cdot B_1(0)$ relate to the image of $B_1(0)$? Don’t forget that $T$ is linear.

Comment: I believe that $T(\lambda B_{1}(0))=\lambda T(B_{1}(0))$, am I wrong?

Comment: That’s right, now if $T(B_0)$ admits a bound $r$, what’s a bound for $T(B_\lambda (0) )$ where $\lambda$ is $>0$?

Comment: Considering the property about the images, I think the bound for $T(B_{\lambda}(0))$ is $\lambda r$, don't it? I dunno